# Override a field in parent class with property in child class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, properties

Where I am now looks like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.x=val
        self.y=42
        # other fields

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=22
        # other fields

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super(C,self).__init__(val)
    @property
    def x(self):
        # if A.x is None return a value that I can compute from A.y and B.a
        # if A.x is not None return it
    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        # set the field value
```

Sometimes I just want to set an assumed value for `x` by hand, in which case I would just use an `A`.  In other cases I want to use a more complicated approach that involves computing `A.x`'s value on the basis of information that is organized into a `B`.  The idea in this code is to make a `C` class that can look like an `A` (in terms of the `x` field) but doesn't need that field value to be set by hand, instead it just gets derived.

What I can't figure out is how to have the `C.x` property shadow the `A.x` field in a sensible way.

Comment: What do you mean *"in a sensible way"*? Could you give a [mcve] of what you've tried to do with this, what you expected and what happened instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `self.x = val` in the `A.__init__` method will simply invoke your `C.x` *setter*. You already have everything handled here. You are handling *per instance* attributes here, not attributes on a class that are inherited by subclasses.

All you need to do is to set a *different* attribute in the setter to represent the `x` value. You could name it `_x`, for example:

```
class C(A, B):
    _x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        if self._x is not None:
            return self._x
        return self.a + self.y

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self._x = val
```

Note that if all `C.__init__` does is call `super().__init__`, you don't need it at all. However, you *do* need to make sure at least `A.__init__()` plays along in the inheritance structure; add in more calls to `super().__init__()`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, val, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = val
        self.y = 42

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a = 22
```

Using `*args` and `**kwargs` allows these methods to pass on any extra arguments to other classes in the hierarchy.

Demo, using the above classes:

```
>>> c = C(None)
>>> c.x
64
>>> c.x = 15
>>> c.x
15
```